# Como trabahar com DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn em c#?

Tags: c#

Estou a ter algumas dificuldades em trabalhar com o campo de seleção da data grid view, tentei fazer desta maneira:

```
public void Atualizar()
 {
     Stock obj = new Stock();

     for (int A = 0; A < dgv_Entrada.RowCount; A++)
     {

         int ID_Cod = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Entrada[1, A].Value);

         obj.id_entrada = ID_Cod;
         obj.estado = cb_Estado.Text;
        }

       obj.Actualizar();

  }
```

Quando executo, ao selecionar mas de uma linha, ele só atualiza os dados da ultima linha selecionada.

Não estou a conseguir fazer uma verifição das linhas selecionadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está errado.

Você está iterando por todas as linhas do seu `datagridview` e depois que você passou por todas e chegou na última você está chamado o método `obj.Actualizar`; ou seja, ele só vai atualizar a última pois é ela que ficou salva na variável.

O correto é você chamar esse método para *cada* linha, ou seja, colocar dentro do laço *`for`*:

```
public void Atualizar()
{
   Stock obj = new Stock();

   for (int A = 0; A < dgv_Entrada.RowCount; A++)
   {
      // Checar se o valor é falso, se for, pula para a próxima linha.
      if(Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_Entrada[/*Nome ou indice coluna checkbox*/, A].Value) == false)
      {
         continue;
      }

      int ID_Cod = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Entrada[1, A].Value);

      obj.id_entrada = ID_Cod;
      obj.estado = cb_Estado.Text;

      obj.Actualizar();
   }
}
```

Comment: Como faço isso? Podes dar um exemplo prático?

Comment: Já fiz, olhe o código que eu postei, eu coloquei o método `obj.Actualizar` dentro do `for`, só isso

Comment: Fazendo assim ele salva todas as linhas, ate as que não selecionei, já ti veira feito desta forma. Tentei fazer uma verificação das linhas que estão a ser selecionado desta forma: int ID_Cod = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Entrada[1, A].Value);
                Boolean x = Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_Entrada["chk_opcao", dgv_Entrada.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());

                if(x==true)  
                {
                    obj.id_entrada = ID_Cod;
                    obj.estado = cb_Estado.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                } mas não resultou

Comment: Pronto, coloquei uma checagem para verificar se o valor está selecionado ou não. Dá uma olhada, apenas coloque o nome ou indice da coluna do checkbox.

Comment: Agora sim funcionou, gratos pela ajuda. Se eu quiser adicionar uma opção de selecionar tudo com uma checkBox aparte, será que vai funcionar se eu por o nome da datagridview .SelectAll ?

Comment: De nada. Só dá para selecionar tudo programaticamente. Siga esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242861/check-all-checkbox-items-on-datagridview

Comment: Consegui o que queria, já esta a funcionar, mas uma veis obrigado por tudo!

Comment: De nada, apenas marque minha resposta como aceita, por favor

Comment: Encontrei mas uma outra dificuldade, já consegui adicionar uma checkBox aparte com a opção de selecionar tudo e esta a funcionar normalmente, acontece que quando seleciono por exemplo duas lunhas e clico em selecionar tudo, ele desabilita os dois campo selecionado anteriormente  e habilita os demais campo que não estavam selecionado, tem ai o codigo:  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Entrada.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool)chk.Value); 
            }